# Downsample variable and interpolate NaN in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Question is

```py
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('dow_jones_index.data',parse_dates=["date"], index_col="date")
dataFrame.head()

closeTS = dataFrame[(dataFrame.stock == 'AA')].close.str.replace('$',' ').astype(float)
```

downsample the data filtered in the above step day wise and perform interpolation to forward fill the first two 'NaN' values.
return the first 10 samples of downsampled data to variable 'downsample'

I tried the below

```py
downsample1 = closeTS.resample('D', fill_method='ffill')
downsample = downsample1.interpolate(method='linear',limit=None,limit_direction='forward')
print(downsample.head(10))
```

however above code does not seem to work

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean? _How exactly_ does it not work? Are you getting errors? Or invalid data?

Comment: I am getting invalid data error

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: import pytest
from test_ts_resample_day import values, ansobj


@pytest.fixture
def usrans(ano):
    ano_values = []
    for data in ano:
        ano_values.append(eval(values.gans[data - 1]))
    return ano_values


@pytest.mark.parametrize("ano, qno ,expected", [([1, 2], '1', ['36ec15883d9d1cf6062fe78eb976732a',
                                                               '287996c06e9f418efda4041d5846c16b'])])
def test_resample_day(usrans, qno, expected):
    assert usrans == expected, "downsample values has failed to pass test cases"

Comment: usrans = ['36ec15883d9d1cf6062fe78eb976732a', '79d11ce0b8a05f07338a56843e5c88d8']

qno = '1'

expected = ['36ec15883d9d1cf6062fe78eb976732a', '287996c06e9f418efda4041d5846c16b']

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("ano, qno ,expected", [([1, 2], '1', ['36ec15883d9d1cf6062fe78eb976732a',

                                                                   '287996c06e9f418efda4041d5846c16b'])])

    def test_resample_day(usrans, qno, expected):

Comment: This is the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
downsample = closeTS.resample('D', fill_method='ffill', limit=2).head(10)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).